# The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship. Error in 1 PC

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, domain-controller

We have a small office with 9 PCs and a Windows Server. Today one PC, Cypher shows this when trying to log in:

> The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship.

I tried logging in with the username Cypher from a different PC, its working fine. Please help me in troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, standard broken trust. Just unjoin and rejoin the domain from a local admin account on the PC "Cypher". That's simplest, though depending on OS, you could also use powershell or netdom to reset the Machine password.

Snide aside, upgrade from Server 2003 as it is EOL in like 2 months...